# A recurrence relation similar to Catalan number

Tags: recurrence-relations, convolution

Consider the convolutional recurrence relation below:  $$T(n)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n−1} k\cdot T(k)\cdot T(n−k) & n\ge2\\ 1 &n=1
\end{cases}$$

Does it have a closed form? Or is it possible to get a tight upper bound of $T(n)$?

Comment: Calculate the first half a dozen values ... then put them in Neil Sloane's on line encyclopedia of integer sequences. ... If this formula has come from a combinatorial evaluation , tell us about it.

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C14%2C85%2C621&sort=&language=english&go=Search